# Firefox 22+ large font workaround

Tags: fonts, firefox

I'm working on a website and Firefox is displaying it's font extremely large. Chrome and Safari are displaying normal font size. Chrome uses the WebKit rendering engine. Firefox uses the Gecko engine. I've found that you can change font display in Firefox by typing

```
about:config
```

in the firefox address bar and changing the

```
 layout.css.devPixelsPerPx
```

value to 1. Although this might work on some systems, I don't want my user to need to do this.

How can I make sure that the font is displayed correctly? I've tried adjusting CSS with

```
-moz-font-size
```

and variants but it doesn't work. I really can't change all my text to images, that's just wrong. Is there a specific syntax for this? Or any suggested workaround that would be optimal?

Chrome[image: Chrome image]

Firefox[image]

Comment: Desktop? Or Mobile? Can you post a screenshot to show the comparison?

Comment: Desktop, I'm on a mac retina display but I've tested on windows systems with normal and 10inch screens and problem reproduces while other browsers display normally. I can't post images (need 10 rep), but this is the concerning website: http://harbingermultimedia.be/

Comment: Your large font appears to be caused by the `font-size-adjust` property (which is only supported by Firefox). Remove this and the font displays at the same size as Chrome. (?)

Comment: ...if you did specify a `font-size-adjust` (aspect value), shouldn't this be a value at least less than 1 (the x-height of a font divided by the font size)? You have specified a value of 1.2, which is _always_ going to produce a much larger font-size.

Comment: You now have 11 rep and you should be able to edit and add the image.

Comment: Btw have you tried using `body {font-size:65%}` `.container{font-size:1rem}` or even using `em`.

Comment: Thank you w3d , solved. It was the 'font-size-adjust' I think. If you make answer, i'll accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified in comments, the extra-large fonts in Firefox would seem to be caused by the `font-size-adjust` property (which, incidentally, is only support by Firefox currently AFAIK). Removing this property altogether (or setting it to an appropriate value - see below) resolves the issue in Firefox.

The idea behind `font-size-adjust` is to make fallback fonts more readable; when their x-heights differ from the primary font. However, this value affects all fonts. I think that ordinarily, the `font-size-adjust` property, as [defined by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-size-adjust), is intended to take the "aspect value" of the *primary font*, which is defined as "the x-height of a font divided by the font size" (which is clearly going to be a lot less than 1). If you specify a larger value than the aspect value of the current font then the font-size is going to increase.

When the primary font is not available, a fallback font is used. If the "aspect value" of the fallback font differs from the specified `font-size-adjust` (aspect value) property then the `font-size` is adjusted. If the specified `font-size-adjust` is the *aspect value* of the primary font, then the fallback font is adjusted to "look" a similar size to the primary font. Different fonts at the same `font-size` can look different sizes because their x-heights differ, and this affects readability. For instance "Verdana" vs "Times New Roman" - Verdana "looks" much bigger at the same `font-size` and consequently is more readable at smaller `font-size`s.

You had initially specified a value of 1.2, which is always going to increase the font-size (of any font!). A value of 1.2 is effectively stating that the height of the lowercase `x` is 20% larger than the uppercase `X`! A more "normal" value for the font you had chosen is 0.54 (my estimate). If you specify a larger value than this, then the default font will be larger in Firefox.

Using [the formula as specified by W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#aspect-ratio-value):

```
  c  =  ( a / a' ) s  
Where
  s  =  font-size value
  a  =  aspect value as specified by the 'font-size-adjust' property
  a' =  aspect value of actual font
  c  =  adjusted font-size to use
```

If you specify a `font-size-adjust` of 1.2, with a specified font-size of 18px, then the resulting font-size of the text in question becomes: (1.2 / 0.54) * 18 = 40px (approx). (Which is clearly very large!)

If you had specified a `font-size-adjust` of 0.54 (which I estimate as the aspect value of your primary font) then the resulting font-size would be (0.54 / 0.54) * 18 = 18. ie. no change.

---

Handy online tool for calculating the `font-size-adjust` (aka "aspect value") of any font installed on your machine:
http://fontdeck.com/support/fontsizeadjust

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation, this was very helpfull. Perfect answer.